# Multiple stylesheet integration

Tags: css

Lets say I have 2 elements in the same page with unique id attributes but same sub elements:

```
<div id="a">
    <div class="book"></div>
    <div class="table"></div>
</div>

<div id="b">
    <div class="book"></div>
    <div class="table"></div>
</div>
```

And I have some css styles in a css file targeting these sub elements:

```
.book{
    background:red;
    color:blue;
}
.table{
    margin:5px;
    border:1px;
}
```

If I link this stylesheet in my head tag, it will target elements in both parent divs same way.

My question is, what is the way to make this css target each instance individually?

Is this the only solution?

```
#a .book{
    background:red;
    color:blue;
}
#a .table{
    margin:5px;
    border:1px;
}

#b .book{
    background:green;
    color:white;
}
#b .table{
    margin:15px;
    border:10px;
}
```

Basically I am writing a plugin which will allow multiple instances in the same page, but its css file should have different settings for each instance. So the only way I can think of is to prefix every css declaration with parent id attribute.

Is there a better way?

Comment: You don't need to add an `id` to each parent. If all the parents are siblings, you can add an `id` only to the grandparent, and select the parents using for example `:nth-child`.

Comment: this looks like an ideal situation to try out [web components](http://css-tricks.com/modular-future-web-components/)

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Of course there are alternatives to all selector choices.

Comment: Lets say you have video player (so many html elements), and one stylesheet for all these elements, but every instance of this video player can be styled differently (different colored buttons, playlist items etc...). So I would place two instances of this video player in the same page. Top element is div with id attribute so they can be differentiated and referenced, but all inner elements are classes. So how do I make 2 stylesheets and reference two players differently without prefixing every elements in stylesheet with id attributes of the player? (like I showed in the example above?)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a class/id/data-attribute on the parent to target it

Or you can use div:nth-child(1) or div:nth-of-type(1), along with a class not to target all div's, for example

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many items you'll have and how you want the styles differentiated, you can use child pseudo-classes on the objects you're currently applying an `id` to.

Here's an example using unordered lists. Note that all the `ul`s need to be enclosed in another block-level object in order for the :###-child psuedo classes to work properly.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul .book{
    background:blue;
    color:orange;
}
ul .table{
    margin:20px;
    border:5px solid black;
}

ul:first-child .book{
    background:red;
    color:blue;
}
ul:first-child .table{
    margin:5px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

ul:nth-child(3) .book{
    background:gray;
    color:blue;
}
ul:nth-child(3) .table{
    margin:30px;
    border:10px solid black;
}

ul:last-child .book{
    background:green;
    color:white;
}
ul:last-child .table{
    margin:50px;
    border:15px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
    <li class="book">Foo</li>
    <li class="table">Bar</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="book">Foo</li>
    <li class="table">Bar</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="book">Foo</li>
    <li class="table">Bar</li>
</ul>
  
<ul>
    <li class="book">Foo</li>
    <li class="table">Bar</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

If you are dynamically adding content using javascript, consider creating a list of classes to plug into each section as needed. You could even randomize the distribution of styles as your page is populated.

Comment: Using nth child isnt going to help as I see it because there will be many deep level nested children within each parent div, so I dont see in the end how this makes for a better solution that prefixing id's for every css elament style declaration.

Comment: How many different styles are you going to need, overall? Also, under what conditions would each of the styles be applied?

Comment: Lets say you have video player (so many html elements), and one stylesheet for all these elements, but every instance of this video player can be styled differently (different colored buttons, playlist items etc...). So I would place two instances of this video player in the same page. Top element is div with id attribute so they can be differentiated and referenced, but all inner elements are classes. So how do I make 2 stylesheets and reference two players differently without prefixing every elements in stylesheet with id attributes of the player? (like I showed in the example above?)

Comment: Well.. without the specificity of that prefix, your second set of styles will likely just cascade over the settings of the first set. If you can incorporate Sass into your project, you could use the nesting feature and just declare the `id` once for each set.

http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-3

Comment: If only I could do this with css.